# Flutter: Return each iteration of loop as new page

Tags: flutter, loops

I have a for loop which returns a class, in the class a widget is selected. I have the problem that it is returning each widget below each other, whereas I would like each widget to be its own 'page' and when the user navigates back to the 'page' with the loop on it, a new iteration of the loop is started.

**Current problematic output**
[image: Problematic Output]

**Game() - iteration**

```
body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              for (roundsindex = 0; roundsindex < rounds; roundsindex++) ...{
                Cards(),
              }
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**Cards() - choose widget**

```
return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          if (currentcat == "starter") ...[
            StarterCard()
          ] else if (currentcat == "rather") ...[
            RatherCard()
          ] else ...[
            SpinBottleCard()
          ],
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**Starter() - example of widget that should take full page**

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Game();
          },
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Text("I am Starter"),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Sorry I am not getting the issue ,Can you include your full widget and what do you expect from this and what went wrong.

Comment: i don't know what do you want

Comment: Using the Problematic Output image as an example, the first blue "I am Starter" line must fill up the complete screen, without any of the lines below it shown yet. When the first blue screen is tapped on, it must bring up the second orange "I am Rather" screen which must fill up the whole screen. When that is tapped on it must bring up the next blue "I am Starter" screen and after that the next brown "I am SpinBottle" screen, and so on.